# plotting multiple plots in R - par

Tags: r, plot, par

I have used `par(mfrow = c(2,2))` to create a matrix of 2x2 plots. This has previously worked just fine. However, this time my plots are all way too small.
I have not changed anything in the code. I guess I must have changed the environment without knowing. **Any ideas how i can revert the changes?** 
[image]
[image]

```
> par(mfrow = c(2,2))
>   par("mar")
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
> 
>   plot(hat.ep,rstudent.ep,col="#E69F00", main="hat-values versus studentized residuals",
+        xlab="Hat value", ylab="Studentized residual")
>   dffits.ep <- dffits(logit_reduced)
>   plot(id,dffits.ep,type="l", col="#E69F00", main="Index Plot",
+        xlab="Identification", ylab="Diffits")
>   cov.ep <- covratio(logit_reduced)
>   plot(id,cov.ep,type="l",col="#E69F00",  main="Covariance Ratio",
+        xlab="Identification", ylab="Covariance Ratio")
>   cook.ep <- cooks.distance(logit_reduced)
>   plot(id,cook.ep,type="l",col="#E69F00", main="Cook's Distance",
+        xlab="Identification", ylab="Cook's Distance")
```

Comment: What do you get if you type `par("mar")` ?

Comment: `> par("mar")
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1`

Comment: Have you tried changing to e.g. `par(mar=c(3,2,2,1))` to see what happens?

Comment: @griffinevo...yes. The plots are normal size, as i want them to be. The same for par(mar=c(2,2))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u would like to get back to 1 row one column plots, use par(mfrow=c(1,1)). 
Shud use  options function to get the computed displays and its results

Before beginning to change any option settings, its better to save old options:

```
old.o <- options()
```

Then to revert back to original can use:

```
options(old.o)
```

## Edit

Try resetting graphics device, and start plots all over again, caution u might loose all the previous plots.
    dev.off()

Comment: maybe the question is not clear. I do not want to go back to par(mfrow=c(1,1)). I want to continue using par(mfrow = c(2,2)), however i do not understand why the size of the plots changed